# What are factors for coverage And Is there any Algorithm for calculating coverage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I am writing unit test cases for Angular (using the Jasmine Framework and Karma) for running the test cases. I need to cover the code by using Coverage-html(Istanbul).

There are different type of coverage :

1. Function.
2. Branches
3. Statements
4. Lines
5. Ignored (using Istanbul we can ignore).

Please explain the different type of coverage and essential factors need to take care when writing unit test cases :

```
function setCookie(sessionId) {
    if(sessionId) {
        setCookie('sessionId', sessionId, 21600);
    } else {
        setCookie('sessionId', session.getId(), 21600);
    }
}
```

I've written test cases for this :

```
describe('setCookie()', function(){
    it('should be set a cookie without expiration days', function() {
        var defered =$q.defer();
        spyOn(sessionCard, 'setCookie').andCallFake(function(){
              return defered.promise;
        })
        sessionCard.setCookie('sessionId', 'sessionId');
        expect(document.cookie).toBeDefined();
        expect(document.cookie).toBeTruthy();
    });
})
```

Comment: branch coverage means you have covered all possible conditions. So for example if(x === true){do this}else{do that} has two branches, one where x is true and one where it isn't. If you write a test for this where x is true then you will have 50% branch coverage.

Answer (score 0):

The points you mentioned to types of coverage are necessary when writing unit test still it never assures that you have covered you code.

There are multiple scenarios for every function to write test.

1. All statements are covered at least once
2. All happy path scenarios are covered
3. All fail safe conditions (negative scenarios/i.e exception blocks) are coverd

If above scenarios are covered you can safe assume your function is fully tested.
Just make sure your test depend on the output and not on specific variable which holds.

Comment: Taj, I totally agreed with your answer.. However when i have covered my test code (100% i.e functions & statements). the coverage for branch is still 55%.. I don't understand the Algorith behind this..

Comment: First of all your code can't be 100% tested unless you have every branch  covered. There may be something with your coverage configuration because you have to have your all statements+all branches covered to make overall coverage as 100%

Comment: if you found it helpful you can accept the answer :)